# Information theory reference: comparison between Mackay to Thomas and Cover

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, information-theory

I'm a computational neuroscience student with a background in mathematics. I want to learn information theory over the summer. I am interested in its applications to neuroscience, machine learning, statistics, etc. I cannot decide between Elements of Information Theory by Cover and Thomas and Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms by David Mackay. I read recommendations saying they are both great. Also I read that while being more theoretically superficial on information theory, Mackay's book is richer in useful applications, e.g.  bayesian inference.

Has anyone read them both? What would you recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: Definitely MacKay, for exactly the reasons you mention.

Comment: @Stelios Should I be concerned that Mackay's book isn't\less rigorous?

Comment: MacKay's book is certainly not a "mathmatician's book" (he was a physicist), but what makes his book great is that it is very well written with motivating examples and discussions. It is certainly not a light read though. On the other hand, Cover&Thomas book style is very "dry" and, honestly, kind of boring. It can be difficult to go through it as a beginner, and I think most of its contents do not fit your interests.

Comment: @Stelios Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both great books, but completely different approaches.  MacKay's book is full of exercises, visual explanations... it tries to convince you of the intuition of concepts first; Cover and Thomas is less visual, less intuitive,  more "mathematical".

Personally, I found the narrative of Cover and Thomas hard to grasp, while MacKay is more well organized and explains to you not only the concepts but why we need them. Conversely, for some reason, I kept going back to Cover and Thomas to understand a specific concept or proof.